# Subclass of ConfigParser has no attribute _sections

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I am trying to subclass ConfigParser. When trying to access `_sections` it says

```
'acc' object has no attribute '_sections'
```

Example Code(python 2.7):

```
import ConfigParser
class acc(object, ConfigParser.RawConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, acc_file):
            super(acc,self).__init__()
            self.lol = 1
            print self.has_section(self.lol)

a=acc(1)
```

Comment: Attributes beginning with an underscore are considered private. See [the docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers)

Comment: Yes, however see the newest code, updated to reflect that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been described much better [here](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).

---

This is Python's [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

So, what actually happens is that the MRO "chaining" does not behave well when encoutering an old style class. Or to be specific - **classes that do not call super**

In your code, `configParser.RawConfigParser__init__(..)` is **never called**. To fix this you could call it manually (simply add `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.__init__(self ...)` in `acc`'s `init`), although I'm not sure this is recommended or even valid.

Your other option is to make all classes conform to the new style, and invoke `super`, or old style, and initialize explicitly.

The only thing that seems to be working is if all classic-style classes are **after** all new-style classes in the output of `Class.mro()`, and specifically after `object`. This will prevent `super` from calling them.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27628664/948550) isn't very safe because of this scenario:

```
class TheClassicClass:
   def __init__(self):
       print "instantiating clasic class!"
       self._msg = "the classic class!"
   def m(self):
       print self._msg

class acc(ConfigParser.RawConfigParser, TheClassicClass, object):
    def __init__(self, acc_file):
            super(acc,self).__init__()
            self.lol = 1
            print self.has_section(self.lol)

a=acc(1)
a.m()
```

**Fix to other answer:** adding these lines to `acc`'s `__init__` should inform to explicitly instantiate the classes:

```
ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.__init__(self)
TheClassicClass.__init__(self)
```

To confirm the problem in your code, let's try to reproduce this problem in a simple setup...

We'll make old (classic) classes:

```
class AClassic:
    def __init__(self):
        print "init aclassic"

class BClassic:
    def __init__(self):
        print "init bclassic"
        self.name = "bclassic"

    def m(self):
        print "print from " + self.name
```

And new style classes that invoke `super`:

```
class ANew(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "init anew"
        super(ANew, self).__init__()

class BNew(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "init bnew"
        super(BNew, self).__init__()

    def m(self):
        print "print from bnew"
```

In the simplest case, we're manually calling `__init__` to make sure classes are instantiated. This would look something like:

```
class TestOldStyle(AClassic, BClassic):
    def __init__(self):
        AClassic.__init__(self)
        BClassic.__init__(self)
        self.m()

print "old style"
TestOldStyle()
```

In this case, [depth-first, left-to-right](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance), is the order of the MRO.

Output:

> old style
>
> init aclassic
>
> init bclassic
>
> print from bclassic

Now let's try new style, which looks like this with `super`:

```
# will init ANew and BNew
class TestNewSuper(ANew, BNew, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNewSuper, self).__init__()

TestNewSuper()
```

Since both classes call `super`, they are both instantiated and the output is:

> init anew
>
> init bnew

Now, we try using some "hybrids" of a classic-style classes ([ConfigParser.RawConfigParser is a classic-style-class](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/ConfigParser.py#L217), and cannot call `super`:

```
# will init ANew , but not BClassic
class TestOldStyleSuper(ANew, BClassic):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestOldStyleSuper, self).__init__()
        self.m()
```

Output:

> init anew

And immediately an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./inhert.py", line 35, in <module>
    TestOldStyleSuper()
  File "./inhert.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.m()
  File "./inhert.py", line 15, in m
    print "print from " + self.name
AttributeError: 'TestOldStyleSuper' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This happens since `BClassic` is not instantiated.

More examples of unexpected behaviour:

```
# init ANew, BClassic
class TestHybrid(ANew, BClassic, BNew):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestHybrid, self).__init__()
        self.m()

TestHybrid()
```

will initialize `ANew` and `BClassic`, but not `BNew`:

> init anew
>
> init bclassic
>
> print from bclassic

And creating an incosistent MRO:

```
# no consistent MRO exception
class TestHybrid(ANew, object, BNew):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestHybrid, self).__init__()
        self.m()

TestHybrid()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./inhert.py", line 33, in <module>
    class TestHybrid(ANew, object, BNew):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases BNew, object
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Nice answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order of subclassing as follows:

```
import ConfigParser

class acc(ConfigParser.RawConfigParser, object):
    def __init__(self, acc_file):
        super(acc, self).__init__()
        self.lol = 1
        print self.has_section(self.lol)

a=acc(1)
```

Comment: Works mysteriously, can any one explain?

Comment: @Reut Sharabani beat me to it with a good explanation below as to why we need to follow this. Check it out.